AVAudioSession().outputVolume returns rounded values instead of the correct volume
I am building a media player with MusicKit and MediaPlayer. When the user presses the volume buttons up or down, I want to reflect that in a Slider.
.onAppear {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

.onReceive(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().publisher(for: \.outputVolume), perform: { value in
    print(value)
    print(AVAudioSession().outputVolume) // All returning the same valuse 
    print(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputvolume)
})

You can increment the volume 16 times before you reach the maximum volume. Same with decrementing the volume. I expect the increments to be 1/16 or 0.0625. Instead it is 0.05 at most times but sometimes the increase is 0.1.
If I use the above statement, I get the following results when increasing my volume from min to max: 0.0; 0.05; 0.15; 0.2; 0.25; 0.3; 0.4; 0.45; 0.5; 0.55; 0.65; 0.7; 0.75; 0.8; 0.9; 1.0
The values 0.1; 0.35; 0.6; 0.85 didn't appear.
When using the control center to adjust the volume and pressing the volume buttons again, other values are missing.
It looks like I am getting the actual values rounded to either 0 or 5.
How can I get the actual volume level from 0.00 to 1.00? Bonus points for a SwiftUIish solution.

Can you post little more code ?

@Shivbaba's son There is no more code that has anything to do with the problem. If you attach these two modifiers to a brand new project, you can reproduce the problem.
